# RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9

Tags: python, api, numpy, matplotlib

I'm going through the API tutorial on New Coder ([this one](http://newcoder.io/api/)) and got the following error when I try to run the program:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 7, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/crash/TestEnv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/home/crash/TestEnv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/home/crash/TestEnv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 12, in <module>
from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/home/crash/TestEnv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I know it isn't my code because I tried running it with the example code too and had the same issue. One answer I saw suggested on here was to try Numpy 1.8, but that didn't work either.

Also, all of this is set up within a virtual environment as directed so I don't think it's an issue of what I have installed elsewhere.

Comment: Your virtualenv is likely borked. Try reinstalling it in a clean virtualenv.

Comment: I started a new virtualenv even with viralwrapper this time around and got eh same error...

Answer (score 4):

Installing packets from file with requirements may cause failures. I mean something like `pip install -r requirements.txt`

It seems to me that pip just installs packets in order without dependencies (first line from file, second line, ...).

I had same issue because of having installed numpy outside of environment and `numpy` *after* `matplotlib` in `requirements.txt` Pip compiled matplotlib with system nympy, after that it installed new numpy and nothing worked.

I just have switched strings and set `matplotlib` after `numpy`. Now it works.

Comment: 1. It is not true that pip does not attempt to resolve dependencies. 2. pip does not guarantee that requirements will be installed in order - it's a bad idea to rely on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

It works for me